# Anchor tag jQuery Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have an Anchor Tag like this

```
    <a href="javascript:anchorScr()" id="anch1" class ="af-link"/>
```

It is taking me two clicks on the anchor tag  to respond to the javascript function anchorScr();

```
function anchorScr() {
jQuery('a').click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
   });
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why my anchorScr() is not called on the first click ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This calls the `anchorScr` function when the anchor is clicked:

```
href="javascript:anchorScr()"
```

The function then attaches a `click` event handler to all `a` elements.

Remove the `href` and just have this:

```
jQuery('a').click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

The code will execute - attaching the `click` event handler to all `a` elements. You should probably only run this on [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure that the page has fully loaded into the DOM.

Comment: As simple as that.Thank you Od.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="anch1" class ="af-link">click here</a>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('a').click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
   });
});
```